# window.confirm always returns false on Safari on iPhone 6S Plus

Tags: javascript, iphone, angularjs, safari, confirm

When running iPhone 6S Plus via Browserstack, the function window.confirm("foo") always returns false. I expect the function to return true when the OK button is clicked/tapped.

I have tried doing a setTimeout when calling the confirm function to no avail. I have not been able to reproduce this error in other browsers. It works fine on iPhone 5S.

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/4Aj1fuP6W6MahgdZEHyK?p=preview

Code snippet:

```
function() {
  var confirmed = $window.confirm("Click OK");
  alert('confirmed: ' + confirmed);
}
```

I expect the alert to say "confirmed: true".

Does anybody know if there is a workaround?

Comment: Hey Mattias, was wondering if you've found a workaround for this bug.

Comment: I did not. I rolled my own confirm dialog modal instead.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of doing a modal, too. Good to hear someone else did the same. Cheers!

Comment: but is this a IS bug or browserstack bug?